# Compute $\log 3$ numerically using power series

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

> Expand $\dfrac 1 x$ in a power series centered at $c = 2$, integrate, and use your result to calculate $\log 3$ to $4$ significant figures.

So I'm kind of lost on how to approach this one. Would I begin by just plugging $3$ into the upper bound of my integral and let $x = 2$ in $\dfrac 1 x$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\log(3)=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{2+x}=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^4}{16}+\ldots\right)\,dx $$
but the integral over $(-1,1)$ of an odd integrable function is zero, hence
$$ \log(3)=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^4}{16}+\ldots\right)\,dx = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2m+1)4^m}$$
where
$$ \sum_{m\geq 6}\frac{1}{(2m+1)4^m}\leq \sum_{m\geq 6}\frac{1}{13\cdot 4^m}=\frac{1}{39936}\approx 2.5\cdot 10^{-5} $$
$$ \sum_{m\geq 6}\frac{1}{(2m+1)4^m}\geq \frac{1}{13\cdot 4^6}\approx 1.8\cdot 10^{-5}$$
and
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{5}\frac{1}{(2m+1)4^m}=\frac{3897967}{3548160}\approx 1.09859$$
so that $\log(3)=\color{red}{1.0986}\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Calculators yield
>   $\ds{\quad\ln\pars{3} = 1.098612288668109\ldots}$

---

1. \begin{align}
\ln\pars{3} & = -\ln\pars{1 \over 3} = -\ln\pars{1 - {2 \over 3}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\pars{2 \over 3}^{n} =
{2 \over 3}  + {2 \over 9} + {8 \over 81} + \cdots
\end{align}
It's quite inefficient since you need $\ds{19}$ terms, at least, to achieve a relative error of $\ds{10^{-2}\ \%}$.

---

2. Another possibility involves $\ds{\expo{}}$ which is 'closer' to $\ds{3}$ than $\ds{2}$:
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{3} & = \ln\pars{\expo{} + \bracks{3 - \expo{}}} =
1 + \ln\pars{1 + {3 - \expo{} \over\expo{}}} =
1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n}\pars{3 - \expo{} \over \expo{}}^{n} 
\end{align}
$$
\begin{array}{rrr}\hline
\ds{N} & \ds{\qquad S_{N} = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{N}
{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n}\pars{3 - \expo{} \over \expo{}}^{n}\qquad} &
\ds{\verts{S_{N} - \ln\pars{3} \over \ln\pars{3}}\ 100\ \%}
\\ \hline \\
\ds{1} & \ds{1.\color{#f00}{10363832351433}\ldots} &
\ds{4.57 \times 10^{-1}\phantom{1}}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1.098\color{#f00}{26787246390}\ldots} &
\ds{3.13 \times 10^{-2}\phantom{1}}
\\
\ds{3} & \ds{1.0986\color{#f00}{3892882615}\ldots} &
\ds{2.42 \times 10^{-3}\phantom{1}}
\\
\ds{4} & \ds{1.09861\color{#f00}{008708167}\ldots} &
\ds{2.00 \times 10^{-4}\phantom{1}}
\\
\ds{13} & \ds{1.0986122886681\color{#f00}{1}\ldots} &
\ds{9.78 \times 10^{-14}}
\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

> Note that $\ds{3}$ decimal places are found with $\ds{n = 2}$ which yields

$$
\ln\pars{3} \approx
-\,{9 \over 2\expo{}^{2}}\, + {6 \over \expo{}} - {1 \over 2}\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{Relative Error} = 3.13 \times 10^{-2}\ \%~}
$$